# Editing HTML structurally

Tags: html, paredit

Recently I've done a lot of work cleaning up some HTML files that were generated by LibreOffice.  It made me *really* wish for a way to edit the document structure, à la `paredit-mode`.

For example, for some reason LibreOffice rendered one particular ordered list like this:

```
<ol>
  <li>...</li>
</ol>
<ol start="2">
  <li>...</li>
</ol>
<ol start="3">
  <li>...</li>
</ol>
<!-- etc -->
```

I would have loved a way to put the point somewhere in the first `ol` and issue a command analogous to `paredit-forward-slurp-sexp` to pull the content of the second list into the first, and then repeat for all the remaining lists.

As another example, I also needed to insert some breaks in a set of nested `div`s:

```
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    ...
    <-- point is here
  </div>
</div>
```

I wished I could issue a command analogous to `paredit-split-sexp` twice to get this:

```
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<-- point is here
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">
  </div>
</div>
```

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Tagedit](https://github.com/magnars/tagedit) is what you want.

From the README:

- tagedit-forward-slurp-tag moves the next sibling into this tag.
- tagedit-forward-barf-tag moves the last child out of this tag.
- tagedit-raise-tag replaces the parent tag with this tag.
- tagedit-splice-tag replaces the parent tag with its contents.
- tagedit-join-tags combines two tags into one, prompting for tagname if they differ.
- tagedit-split-tag splits a tag into two.
- tagedit-convolute-tags switches the parents of the current tag, along with previous siblings.
- tagedit-kill kills to the end of the line, while preserving the structure.